# Is there a grammatical rule impeding the presence of 'for' in "I have lived here 'for' all my life"?

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. I have lived here all my life.
> 2. I have lived here ***for*** all my life.

Yes, 1 is perfectly 'standard' English, but I wonder why one [cannot add ***for***](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=here%20all%20my%20life,%20here%20for%20all%20my%20life&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) to 1  before 'all my life'?

Is there a grammatical rule governing this matter? If so, can anybody explain such rule?

I'm asking because in my language, as far as I know, both 1 and 2 are acceptable, with and without ***for*** (*per*).

Comment: Although you may hear such a "for" inserted in casual, everyday speech, it shouldn't really be there. More about this rule can be found [HERE](http://books.google.com/books?id=W_AJXhv2OsoC&pg=PA24&dq=%22for+all+my+life%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0OgLUcaCM8jL0AHIyIC4Cg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22We%20do%20not%20use%20for%20with%20all%22&f=false).

Answer (score 4):

I think you just have to accept that when *all* comes before words that express any length of time, it cannot be preceded by *for*.

Comment: I'm not sure that will hold true for all eternity...

Comment: Unless the _for_ is not starting a prepositional phrase (as in, "That is what I've been hoping for all my life," or, "This is what I've been waiting for all summer").

Comment: I don't think your rule is correct.  http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/272652-and-for-all-those-years-we-never-talked-about-the

Comment: And this settles the matter `once and for all`?

Comment: @snailplane. Oh, I don’t make rules, but well spotted anyway. I think the difference is that the Amy Tan quotation, with its use of the past tense in the main clause, refers to a particular time in the past. A clause like _I have lived here all my life_ uses the present perfect construction, and refers to time up until now.

Comment: @J.R. interesting examples! English is not my native language, but I think in your examples the verbs are basically *"hope for" / "wait for"* and not just *"hope" / "wait"*, I mean the *"for"* is strictly connected to the verb it's required even if you don't use *"all"*, i.e.: *"I hope for something" / "I'm waiting for her"*. While in the phrase *"I lived here when I was young"*, the *"for"* is not required at all.

Comment: You will regret this for all eternity. ;p

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Barrie England's reply, I just wanted to add some reference to go by, but the only text I could find where this rule is referred to clearly is Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*, 3rd edition, section 208, where he states

> ... And ***for*** is not usually used before ***all***.

Comment: And my reference, which I should have shown, is ‘An A-Z of English Grammar and Usage’ by Leech and others: ‘We omit **for** in front of **all**.